# How to disable the backspace key in user textbox when i press spacebar?

Tags: javascript, html

window.onload = function() {

```
};

function preventBackspace(e) {
  var evt = e || window.event;
  if (evt) {
    var keyCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
    if (keyCode === 8) {
      if (evt.preventDefault) {
        evt.preventDefault();
      } else {
        evt.returnValue = true;
      }
    }
    if (keyCode === 46) {
      if (evt.preventDefault) {
        evt.preventDefault();
      } else {
        evt.returnValue = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I used this code to disable backspace if spacebar is pressed but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to disable whitespace

```
<script>

  // delete 8
  // space key 32
  let str = '';
  let bool = false

  function preventBackspace(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
      bool = true
    }
    if (bool && e.keyCode == 8) {
      e.target.value = str;
    }else{
      str = e.target.value;
    }
  }
</script>
<input type="text" onKeyup="preventBackspace(event)">
```

Comment: not work @vue ang

Comment: <script>
    function preventBackspace(e) {
      const value=e.target.value
      e.target.value=value.trim()
    }
  </script>
<input type="text" onInput="preventBackspace(event)">

Comment: Sir I have put this code in my file but I want backspace not to work when I press spacebar, than Backspace doesn't work sir

Comment: Did all the delete keys after the space bar become invalid?If you can give a satisfaction

Comment: Sir, when I am using this, two characters are getting erased from backspace after giving space but I want that after pressing space, there should be no word behind erased by backspace

Comment: You can simply disable input after entering Spaces